# How to count the all child nodes of parent inside for Loop in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

need to count the number of childs and Grand Childs of Parent Node in all child Levels for the following XML.

> How to find,  number of childs under `<regPackagingHierarchyList>` with
>   node as `<recordId>`

**I tried following Code**

```
<xsl:for-each select="LSRIMSData/agl_result/RegistrationPackaging/regPackagingHierarchyList/RegistrationPackagingHierarchy[recordId/text()!='']">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(child::regParentPackagingHierarchy/RegistrationPackagingHierarchy/recordId/node())"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**Source XML:**

```
<agConnectXML>
  <SourceData>
    <SKUIDOut noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///c:/Users/BODDUAV1/OneDrive%20-%20Novartis%20Pharma%20AG/Avanthi/NovaRIM/Documents/SHAPE/stockKeepingUnit.xsd" schemaVersion="1.0">
      <SystemMessageHeader>
        <CreationDateTime>2002-10-10T12:00:00-05:00</CreationDateTime>
        <SenderID>sandoz</SenderID>
        <BusinessSystemID>SHAPE-P34-SKU</BusinessSystemID>
        <MessageID>678678-2389789-4893947-473946</MessageID>
      </SystemMessageHeader>
      <stockKeepingUnit>40</stockKeepingUnit>
      <stockKeepingUnitStatus>Approved</stockKeepingUnitStatus>
      <nationalTradeItemNumber>098098</nationalTradeItemNumber>
      <registrationId>REG-00000026</registrationId>
      <finishedDosageFormId>FDF-002</finishedDosageFormId>
      <activeSusbstanceId>6437</activeSusbstanceId>
      <tenant>sandoz</tenant>
    </SKUIDOut>
  </SourceData>
  <LSRIMSData>
    <agl_result>
      <agl_service_headers>
        <serviceId>CustgetRegPackDetails</serviceId>
        <messageProducer>agidmp</messageProducer>
        <internalVersion>12077</internalVersion>
        <uuid>5670bf06-4f0a-4f0f-ab93-2d2ad99a7384</uuid>
        <dateFormat>yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss</dateFormat>
        <generatedTimeStamp>2019-04-04 20:02:09</generatedTimeStamp>
        <user>system</user>
      </agl_service_headers>
      <agl_pagination_details>
        <start>0</start>
        <limit>10</limit>
        <totalRecordsCount>1</totalRecordsCount>
      </agl_pagination_details>
      <RegistrationPackaging>
        <productPackaging>
          <ProductPackaging>
            <packagingItemName>FDF-002</packagingItemName>
          </ProductPackaging>
        </productPackaging>
        <regIncludedProduct>
          <RegistrationIncludedProduct>
            <recordId>43893</recordId>
            <registration>
              <Registration>
                <dataState>C</dataState>
                <recordId>43887</recordId>
                <registrationUID>REG-00000026</registrationUID>
              </Registration>
            </registration>
          </RegistrationIncludedProduct>
        </regIncludedProduct>
        <regPackagingHierarchyList>
          <RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
            <recordId>43914</recordId>
            <regParentPackagingHierarchy>
              <RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
                <recordId>43912</recordId>
              </RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
            </regParentPackagingHierarchy>
            <regPkgHierarchyDataCarrierList></regPkgHierarchyDataCarrierList>
            <regErpCodesList></regErpCodesList>
          </RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
          <RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
            <recordId>43916</recordId>
            <regParentPackagingHierarchy>
              <RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
                <recordId>43914</recordId>
                <regParentPackagingHierarchy>
                  <RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
                    <recordId>43912</recordId>
                    <regParentPackagingHierarchy>
                      <RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
                        <recordId>43916</recordId>
                      </RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
                    </regParentPackagingHierarchy>
                  </RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
                </regParentPackagingHierarchy>
              </RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
            </regParentPackagingHierarchy>
            <regPkgHierarchyDataCarrierList></regPkgHierarchyDataCarrierList>
            <regErpCodesList></regErpCodesList>
          </RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
        </regPackagingHierarchyList>
      </RegistrationPackaging>
    </agl_result>
  </LSRIMSData>
</agConnectXML>
```

Expected result will be in the following format

> Count(regParentPackagingHierarchy/RegistrationPackagingHierarchy/RecordIds)
>   = 1 Count(regParentPackagingHierarchy/RegistrationPackagingHierarchy/RecordIds)
>   = 3

Answer (score 0):

> How to find, number of childs under `<regPackagingHierarchyList>` with
>   node as `<recordId>`

There is only one instance of  `regPackagingHierarchyList` in your input. Assuming you meant `RegistrationPackagingHierarchy`, and that you actually want to count all `recordId` elements that are **descendants** (not only children) of each `RegistrationPackagingHierarchy`, you could try something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/agConnectXML">
    <xsl:for-each select="LSRIMSData/agl_result/RegistrationPackaging/regPackagingHierarchyList/RegistrationPackagingHierarchy">
        <xsl:text>count = </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(descendant::recordId)"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Given your XML example, the result will be:

```
count = 2
count = 4
```